# What will happen if I, as a count, give a vassal a county?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

What will happen if I, as a count, give a vassal a county?

Will I lose the county like a duke who gives an extra duchy?

Comment: I am going to assume you meant "duchy".

Answer (score 3):

While Paul Marshall is correct, he doesn't answer the implied question, so:

Yes - like giving away a second duchy as a duke - the county you give away will become independent. The reason being you can only have vassals who have a lower rank than yours.

If you want to keep the county within your realm, you will need to create or usurp a duchy title first.

Answer (score 1):

If you give someone a title, you don't have that particular title anymore.  If it's your last title of that level, then your rank goes down to whatever title you have left.

For example, you're a Duke with one duchy, one county, and one city.  You give the duchy away, and now you're a Count (your largest remaining title).  You give the county away, and now you're a Mayor (because all that's left is your city).

If you're a Count, and you own two counties, then giving away one of them will not remove your title of Count.